# How to add cells consecutively after an interval of three cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Screenshot of data]I have 18 years of monthly data i.e., I have 18*12 = 216 cells arranged in a row. I have to add JJAS (June 01 July 01 August 01 September 01) and then ONDJF (Oct 01 Nov 01 Dec 01 Jan 02 Feb 02) values. I want to skip MAM. I have to repeat this procedure for all 18 years.

I can do this manually but want to automate it.

I want JJAS 01 ONDJF 01-02 JJAS 02 ONDJF 02-03...

Comment: Can you provide a sample data screenshot?

Comment: I have added just now. Please click on it.

Answer (score 0):

If Column B contains dates and Column C contains text then putting this formula in Column A will result in Column A having text for JJASONDJF and empty cells MAM.

`=IF(OR(MONTH(B1)<3,MONTH(B1)>5),C1,"")`

If dates are in Row 2 then putting this formula in Row 1 will display the date.

`=IF(OR(MONTH(A2)<3,MONTH(A2)>5),A2,"")`

Comment: I have all months arranged in a row. Can you change your formula accordingly?

Comment: If you transpose your data to put dates in a column then you will be able to use auto filter to hide MAM.   Excel literally makes it as easy as copy and paste. Not sure what your data looks like but you might be pleased with the results.